# Is it Starman or is it the Roadster?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

After the test flight of the Falcon Heavy, we've gotten a flood of questions related to its wonderfully quirky payload. Before the launch, this payload was known as 'the Roadster', and we created a [roadster](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roadster) tag. On launch day, it was officially named Starman by SpaceX. It has generated so much interest among the general public, we have now gotten a slew of questions about Starman, and some of those don't refer to it being a Roadster at all. In fact, in the case of some questions, I think the asker doesn't know it's a Roadster. They just know it's a car.

The procedure when there are two common terms for the same thing is to create two tags, and make one a synonym of the other, so that a search for either will include questions tagged with all the synonyms. But one tag rules them all - the others are added as part of it, more or less.

So, do we create the Starman tag and make it the one true tag, or make it a sub-term of Roadster?

Or do we even change the Roadster tag to Starman?

Comment: Sorry if I add any confusion, but I renamed the roadster tag to [tag:tesla-roadster]. I figured that way it will come up when people start typing "tesla". There were already two roadster questions that had a "tesla" tag instead of a "roadster" tag. I have now replaced the tag on those with the new "tesla-roadster" tag.

Comment: @called2voyage yes, that tesla tag is an issue. It has nothing to do with space. Can it be killed? I don't remember.

Comment: It will die automatically without any questions on it.

Answer (score 18):

Starman is in the Roadster, so therefore the correct tag should be Roadster. I think Starman should be a synonym of Roadster.

According to Space-Track, the name is "TESLA ROADSTER/FALCON 9H", so it would seem Roadster should be the master tag.

Also, Horizons calls it "Tesla Roadster (AKA: Starman, 2018-017A)", or when choosing it as an option "SpaceX Roadster (spacecraft) (Tesla)".

Bottom line, Roadster or Tesla Roadster are the appropriate names. Starman is better picked up in popular culture, but isn't really required.

Comment: Oh, Starman is just the suit? I regarded it as the collective term for the whole thing.

Comment: I always thought Starman was the suit, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @kimholder I can't find a clear statement from Musk or SpaceX on the matter, but most news articles are referring to the suit as Starman.

Comment: Starman is clearly the *mannequin* inside the suit, people.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Well, yes, of course.

Comment: [Someone has created the starman tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starman). You might want to synonym that too

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I concur with @PearsonArtPhoto's [answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/947/12102):

[Jonathan McDowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_McDowell) has tweeted the Satellite Catalog. I noticed this in a [retweet by the Air Force Space Command](https://twitter.com/AFSpace/status/961371676582797313) itself!

[image]

Therefore it's probably OK, this one time, to show it here.

McDowell's tweeted image, cropped:

[image: Satellite Catalog Screen Shot from a tweet cropped]

Also, JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) lists it as Roadster:

[image]